# Pointer to function in ROM

Tags: c, embedded

I have microcontroler that I am working with. When debugging it is necessary to call a function from that is hard coded in ROM. Technical Reference shows how to do this:

```
# define Device_cal (void(*)(void))0x3D7C80
```

and calling procedure looks like this:

```
(*Device_cal)()
```

I can't understand what actually happens here, so my question is:
How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#define` causes `(*Device_cal)()` to be expanded into this immediately before compiling:

```
(*(void(*)(void))0x3D7C80)()
```

The `void(*)(void)` is a declaration for a function pointer that takes `void` and returns `void` types. The `(*())` represents a cast for the next token in the expression (`0x3D7C80`). Thus this asks to treat the data at location `0x3D7C80` as a function. The final `()` calls the function with no arguments.

Answer (score 7):

`void (*) (void)` is a type. It's a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and returns `void`.

`(void(*)(void)) 0x3D7C80` casts the `0x3D7C80` integer to this function pointer.

`(*Device_cal)()` calls the function.

`(Device_cal)()` would do the exactly the same.

The parentheses around `*Device_cal` and `Device_cal` are required because otherwise the cast  to the integer would not have the higher precedence.

Answer (score 2):

well, you "define" a pointer to function, and call it.
`void(*)(void)` mean a pointer to function, that gets no arguments, and return `void`.
If you cast `0x3D7C80` to that type, and call it, you basically call the function that its address is `0x3D7C80`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer (that has already been done satisfactorily), but some advice:

I would suggest the following method instead:

```
typedef void (*tVOID_ROMFUNCTION_VOID)( void ) ;

tVOID_ROMFUNCTION_VOID Device_cal = (tVOID_ROMFUNCTION_VOID)0x3D7C80 ;

Device_cal() ;
```

That way you can create any number of global function pointers on initialisation while the calls look like normal statically linked functions.  And you avoid confusing pre-processor macros voodoo at the same time.

By creating different function-pointer types with different signatures, the compiler will be able to perform some parameter type checking for you too.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer doesn't have more up votes.  It's much cleaner than the macro solutions.

Comment: @tom: Thanks, but to be fair as I said, it is not really an answer to the question asked, just a better way of doing what was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is pasted in which creates a temporary (un named ) pointer to a function at a fixed memory location and then calls it via dereferencing.