# Calling function from ARM microcontroller's ROM by using pointer to this function?

Tags: c, pointers, arm, rom

I am working with `cec1702` (`cortex m4` from microchip), this device a has `cryptographic engine`, but it is accessible only through microchip's API. I don't want to use official `API`, because I am trying to use minimal setup only with `gcc` and for `API` I would need to download the whole `IDE`, also I need just a couple of functions..

In document about device's `ROM` I've founded this list of `API` functions and their symdef table, for example:

```
api_rng_mode                        = 0x00007425; 
api_rng_get_random_bytes            = 0x00007441;
```

Prototypes of this two functions look like this:

```
void api_rng_mode(uint8_t tmode_pseudo);
uint32_t api_rng_get_random_bytes ( uint8_t *pbuff8,uint32_t num_bytes);
```

**MY PLAN** is to use those functions only by defining pointers to them, but am Am I actually doing it right? 
For those **2** examples I am using this definitions:

```
#define api_rng_mode (void(*)(uint8_t))0x00007425
#define api_get_random_bytes (uint32_t(*(uint8_t,uint32_t))0x00007441
```

And in code I call them like this:

```
(*api_rng_mode)(1);
(*api_get_random_bytes)(p, numberofbytes);
```

But so far it doesn't look working... Any ideas?

EDIT: Thank you all for your help:) It works now and I learned something new:) 
The code before jumped somewhere into ROM and stucked there, but it was solved by resetting RNG during the process of setting it up.

Comment: Is the program jumping to correct address when you call that function?

Comment: "Am I actually doing it right?" -- try it and verify the results. If you can't, how could you distinguish a correct from an incorrect answer here? That said, using non `ALL_UPPERCASE` macros is bad coding style and using `#define` in general has a few drawbacks.

Comment: The latter signature should probably be `(uint32_t(*)(uint8_t,uint32_t))` ?

Comment: *"But so far it doesn't look working"* How is it not working?  Doesn't compile? Error message? Crash? Something else? Please [edit] your question, and include missing information.

Comment: This question may have been answered by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919343/pointer-to-function-in-rom) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919343/pointer-to-function-in-rom

Answer (score 4):

The code may well be correct, but it is borderline unreadable with the added problem of macros that don't respect scopes. Therefore:

```
// alias the function types by just adding a `typedef`
typedef void api_rng_mode_function(uint8_t tmode_pseudo);
typedef uint32_t api_rng_get_random_bytes_function( uint8_t *pbuff8,uint32_t num_bytes);
```

That also makes it easier to e.g. mock the functions for unit tests. Then, define pointers to these functions:

```
// TODO: Add reference to documentation where these magic numbers came from!
api_rng_mode_function*const api_rng_mode = 0x00007425;
api_rng_get_random_bytes_function*const api_rng_get_random_bytes = 0x00007441;
```

You can then call the according functions using plain function syntax:

```
api_rng_mode(42);
uint8_t buffer[17];
uint32_t res = api_rng_get_random_bytes(buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

Note that the explicit dereferencing (with `*`) isn't necessary, although it can be done.

The only thing that might still cause problems now is "calling conventions", which is the stack protocol, i.e. the way how arguments are passed on the stack. If the calling function pushes them in the wrong order or if the called function expects some arguments in registers instead, you may need to tell the compiler or even write some inline assembly.

Comment: This is much better. I would also cast these addresses to avoid "int to pointer" warnings.

Comment: in this case typedefing does not make too much sense

Comment: Why do you think so, @P__J__?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not P__J__, but since the `typedef` is only used once, it can seem a bit unnecessary (at least to me). On the other hand, it's going to be used twice when you add the cast to allow integer literal to be assigned to a pointer. :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `unwind` has actually answered it. It makes sense if you use the frequently or you want to return or pass the function pointer (the syntax without the typedefs is quite difficult for humans to read) tec etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want yo use defines you need to pas the parameters as well

```
#define api_rng_mode(p) ((void(*)(uint8_t))0x00007425)(p)
#define api_get_random_bytes(p,s) ((uint32_t (*)(uint8_t *,uint32_t))0x00007441)(p,s)
```

But actually I would wrap them  into the inline functions like this:

```
inline uint32_t api_get_random_bytes(uint8_t *buff, uint32_t size)
{
    return ((uint32_t (*)(uint8_t *,uint32_t))0x00007441)(buff,size);
}
```